# Interesting generics-related discrepancy between javac and Eclipse IDE compiler

Tags: java, eclipse, generics

I have an interesting discrepancy between javac and Eclipse IDE compiler, and can't figure out who's right. So, the code below compiles with javac, however Eclipse tells me that the static initializer's invocation of "exportAll" is wrong, 'cause:

> The method exportAll(Iterable< X.Stat< ? extends Number>>) in the type X is not applicable for the arguments (Collection< capture#1-of ? extends X.Stat>)

Who's right? javac or Eclipse?

```
import java.util.Map;

public class X {
  interface Stat<T> {
  }

  public static void exportAll(Iterable<Stat<? extends Number>> vars) {
  }

  public static Map<Double, ? extends Stat> getPercentiles() {
    return null;
  }

static {
  exportAll(getPercentiles().values());
}
```

}

Comment: getPercentiles should also be static, no? Otherwise it won't compile on either ;)

Comment: this example notwithstanding, there have been bugs in the eclipse java compiler where it outright rejects generics constructs accepted by the sun java compiler.  More recently I've encountered the opposite case, where eclipse 3.7 accepts an inference which sun's 6u21 rejects.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It doesn't compile in javac. (after adding static to getPercentiles)

Get your facts straight; don't waste other people's time.

Kids today, too much ADD.

Comment: Hm… apparently you're right; I tried to create a small reproducible case pulled out from an otherwise humongous build, and that build definitely compiles (which is puzzling). I also verified that the small reproducible case doesn't compile in Eclipse, but you're right that I didn't run the small case through javac. It indeed gives a compilation error, making me wonder why the large build succeeds. I'll have to dig into that now.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Map<Double, ? extends Stat>.values()` will have a type of `Collection<? extends Stat>`. This `Stat` is really `Stat<?>`. Your `Iterable` requires that the `Stat` not just be any old `Stat<?>` but rather `Stat<? extends Number>`. You would have to change your `getPercentiles()` to be `Map<Double, ? extends Stat<? extends Number>>`.

```
public static void exportAll(Iterable<Stat<? extends Number>> vars) {
}                                  //      ^ this must match
                                   //     your values type on the map

public Map<Double, ? extends Stat<? extends Number>> getPercentiles() {
    return null;
}
```

@emboss here's what I would do in those cases whenever I could:

```
class Main {

    static interface Something<E> {
        void doSomething();
    }

    static class ConcreteSomething<E> implements Something<E> {
        E data;
        ConcreteSomething(E data) {
            this.data = data;
        }
        public void doSomething() {
            System.out.println(data);
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Something<Number>> list = new LinkedList<Something<Number>>();
        list.add(new ConcreteSomething<Number>(Math.PI)); // an autoboxed Double
        list.add(new ConcreteSomething<Number>(new Integer(5))); // an Integer

        for(Something<Number> s : list) s.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: Interestingly, that doesn't work in Eclipse either; I tried several variations. This works however (removing "? extends"):


    public static Map<Double, Stat<? extends Number>> getPercentiles() {
      return null;
    }

Comment: Personally I don't like to use the `? extends` notation. I would use `Stat<Number>` and if someone wanted to put a `Stat<Double>` or `Stat<BigInteger>` in I wouldn't care what they did.

Comment: @glowcoder: That won't work, Stat<Double> is not a subtype of Stat<Number>. It has to be the ugly '? extends'...

Comment: @emboss you appear to be correct on that. I'll adapt it to say I'd rather use classes that support generics. As an example, I'll edit in a little code that illustrates how (after some revision) I would prefer to use generics and polymorphism. (Obviously if the libraries I'm working with don't support it, then there's nothing I can do!)

Answer (score 1):

You can't compile your example - you are calling a non-static method `getPercentiles` from the static initializer, so I'll assume that it is a static method, too.

In any case, your compiler would at least spit out an "unchecked" warning if you compile with `-XLint:unchecked` (Stat takes a type parameter!). I assume you would like the following:

```
public class X {
    interface Stat<T> {
}

public static void exportAll(Iterable<? extends Stat<? extends Number>> vars) {
}

public static Map<Double, ? extends Stat<Double>> getPercentiles() {
    return null;
}

static {
    exportAll(getPercentiles().values());
}
```

I assume that your percentiles are an arbitrary subclass of `Stat<Double>`, therefore I declared them as `? extends Stat<Double>` in the Map. So the `values()` call will return a `Collection<? extends Stat<Double>>`.

`Collection` implements `Iterable`, therefore we are safe on that side.But `Collection<? extends Stat<Double>>` is not covered by `Iterable<Stat<? extends Number>>`, therefore we need to declare the argument as `Iterable<? extends Stat<? extends Number>>`.

The beauty (well, except for the syntax) of having `exportAll` take `Iterable<? extends Stat<? extends Number>>` is that your `Map` could contain all sorts of `? extends Stats<N>` where `N` is a subclass of `Number`.

Comment: Thanks. Now, this isn't actually a code I wrote, I'm just trying to use it -- my usage is the "exportAll(getPercentiles().values())" line. I could find a way to modify it; indeed the same solution you propose.

My question, however, was why it compiles with javac but not with Eclipse. As @irreputable correctly noticed, the little example doesn't compile with javac either, which is quite puzzling given it compiles the largish source code body from which I extracted the example.